# Pérdida de puntos por algún usuario eliminado

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, usuarios

Varias veces me ha pasado que, porque algun usuario ha sido eliminado, he perdido puntos de reputación

**¿Qué culpa tengo yo o cualquiera que le haya respondido a ese usuario, que el mismo haya sido eliminado?**

Creo que si a ese usuario se le respondió, y la respuesta es buena, la misma debe perdurar y no eliminar la publicacion del usuario, quizá debería etiquetarse como una publicación cerrada o marcarla de alguna forma.

Ya sé y he leido que si el usuario eliminado tiene una puntuacion alta esto no debe ocurrir, solo ocurre con usuarios eliminados con puntuacion baja, y yo me pregunto entonces

**¿Acaso los usuarios con puntuacion baja no hacen buenas preguntas que reciben buenas respuestas?**

Stackoverflow tiene muchas cosas buenas, pero hay cosas en la que nos enredamos demasiado, si los puntos fueron ganados, pues que se queden

¿Por qué quitarselos al que se los gano por razones ajenas a su voluntad?

Además, cuando eliminan esa publicación no te enteras cuál fué, solamente pierdes los puntos, no puedes saber cuál fué esa publicación la que tú respondiste y recibiste el voto.

Comment: Los puntos se pierden solo en algunos casos puntuales y cuando quien los dio, no dio los suficientes. Esto es para evitar sockpupping y otras cosas. Cuantos puntos perdiste?

Comment: @gbianchi , lo que sea que haya perdido yo me los gané(aunque halla sido 1 pto), si te los ganaste no deberias perderlo en ningun caso que sea ajeno a ti, o acaso a ti te gustaria que te descontaran de tu salario pq otra persona de tu oficina pidio la renuncia.Por otra parte no se que es sockpupping, como dije en mi pregunta, a veces nos inventamos reglas que en lugar de facilitarnos la vida nos la complican mas.

Comment: @Japv [sockpuppeting](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuenta_de_usuario_t%C3%ADtere) es la práctica de crear cuentas falsas con la intención de engañar y obtener algún beneficio. Tristemente, se dan muchas en StackOverflow por parte de usuarios que quieren inflar su reputación de forma fraudulenta (p.e. votándose a sí mismos, a menudo intentando "esconderlo" votando también a otros). Cuando esas cuentas se eliminan, sus puntos son eliminados también. Puede parecer que no es justo (especialmente para el inocente que no tenía nada que ver), pero lo es.

Comment: No termino de entender a qué te refieres con los usuarios de puntuación baja o alta,  y que los puntos se quedan con unos pero no con otros. ¿Podrías añadir más detalles o algún ejemplo concreto? Los puntos funcionan igual para usuarios con alta o baja reputación, y si se eliminan las cuentas, no importa que tuvieran 1 punto o 1.000 puntos, el resultado es el mismo al final.

Comment: No veas SOes como una competencia de puntos y medallas.

Comment: Nose porque no entiendes, @gbianchi ya te explico bien. Hay usuarios que crean cuentas falsas y estos son eliminados. ¿Quieres puntos de una cuenta falsa? Si es asi, entonces estarias a favor del "sockpuppeting". Por otro lado reafirmo lo que dice Candid Moe, no veas el sitio como una competencia

Comment: @JuanRivera, entiendo lo de las cuentas falsas, pero eso no siempre es lo que pasa, hay veces que el mismo usuario solicita la eliminacion de su cuenta o elimina su publicacion, eliminando asi las respuestas dadas, a ver dime, en esos casos tiene sentido que el que responde pierda ptos porque otro decidio eliminarse

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, me referia a esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed, especificamente al segundo parrafo

Comment: @gbianchi, te repito lo que dije en el comentario a Juan Rivera, lo de las cuentas falsas se puede entender, pero que pasa si el propio usuario pide que su cuenta sea eliminada o elimina la publicacion donde ya hay respuestas que recibieron votos y quiza hayan sido hasta aceptadas por el mismo. Por otra parte porque uno no se entera de cual fue la respuesta que le eliminaron.

Comment: @gbianchi, lo de las cuentas falsas es un problema que se que a corto plazo es dificil de hallarle una solucion, pero tienen que haber variantes no podemos conformarnos

Comment: @Japv creo que tu pregunta deberia ser "¿Cuanto es mucha reputación?" porque si el usuario es eliminado o pide que lo elimien, no afectara a los demas. Tambien agregaria la pregunta "¿Afectaria a un usuario activo de poca reputacion los puntos de otros cuando es eliminado?"

Comment: @JuanRivera, donde es que te explican eso, como sabes que es asi?

Comment: @Japv en el link que mandastes, ahi dice "*excepto si el usuario tenía mucha reputación*"(segundo parrafo), por eso indago que deberias hacer esas preguntas que menciono

Comment: @JuanRivera, y que tiene que ver con que tenga poca reputacion, no entiendes, si el usuario no es una cuenta falsa que importa si tiene mucha o poca reputacion, como dije antes, acaso los usuarios con poca reputacion no hacen buenas preguntas y dan buenas respuestas tambien. De verdad que no te entiendo

Comment: @Japv leistes todo el propio link del segundo parrafo que mandastes?? "*En estos casos el equipo usa un borrado especial que preserva los votos, siendo el resultado que no hay cambios de reputación para aquellos que han recibido votos de ese usuario.*" Claramente dice que los usuarios con mucha reputacion que son eliminados no afectaran a los demas. Por eso te digo que hagas las preguntas que digo, pero veo que no entiendes

Comment: @JuanRivera, muchacho, el que no entiendes eres tu, da lo mismo si el usuario eliminado tiene mucha o poca reputacion, nadie deberia perder ptos por la eliminacion de otro usuario tenga este mucha o poca reputacion, Ej si un usuario con 1 pto, me acepto una respuesta entonces obtengo 15 ptos y el tendria entonces 3ptos, al dia siguiente este usuario de 3ptos pide que le borren el perfil, entonces al tratarse de un usuario de una puntuacion tan baja, a mi se me borrarian los 15 ptos que el me dio, si el usuario eliminado tuviese 5000 ptos, yo no perderia esos 15 ptos.Continuara...

Comment: @JuanRivera, lo que yo propongo es que no se pierdan los ptos que ganas tenga la reputacion que tenga el usuario eliminado. Olvidate del cuanto es mucha reputacion, da lo mismo si el usuario tiene 1pto o 5000, si tus ptos fueron bien ganados no deberias perderlos por razones ajenas a ti

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias aseveraciones incorrectas:

- Cuando se elimina la cuenta de un usuario no se eliminan sus publicaciones sino los puntos que dío y esto pueden ser *downvotes* o *upvotes*. Si en la pregunta del usuario eliminado él te dío un UV entonces perderas puntos, pero si te dio DV entonces ganaras puntos(en realidad en ambos casos es una recuperación ya sea negativa o positiva), lo mismo sucede con la aceptación de la respuesta. Si otro usuario te dío UV/DV entonces eso se mantendrá independiente del que el AP elimino su cuenta o no.

Generalmente, las cuentas eliminadas son de usuarios que tuvieron poca actividad en el sitio por lo que la pérdida de puntos es mínima(si eres un gran contribuidor al sitio entonces la pérdida o ganancia es márginal). Por ello existe la regla que si la cuenta eliminada es de un usuario con mucha actividad entonces no se elimina los puntos ya que su eliminación puede tener un alto impacto en la comunidad. Eso no tiene nada que ver con la reputación sino con la actividad del usuario en el sitio.

¿Para que es necesario saber que preguntas o usuario se elimino? ¿si lo supieras que harías? Se debe hacer notar que si se elimina la cuenta de un usuario entonces no se elimina las preguntas ni las respuestas asociadas(salvo casos muy excepcionales).

Comment: Pues en ambos casos esta mal que funcione de esa forma, ademas entre UV y DV hay una gran diferencia, un DV son -2 ptos, mientras que un UV son 10 ptos y una respuesta aceptada son 15 ptos, como ves te afecta mas no recuperar ptos positivos que recuperar ptos negativos

Comment: @Japv En todo mi tiempo en SO la mayor pérdida unitara ha sido de 50pts qué es màrginal. Eso de malo o bueno es altamente subjetivo, si estan en las reglas entonces no es ni malo ni bueno ya que en teoria debiste conocerlas

Comment: "¿Para que es necesario saber que preguntas o usuario se elimino?", yo no quiero saber que usuario se elimino, no fue eso lo que quise decir, a mi lo que me interesa saber cual fue mi respuesta que se elimino con esa publicacion eliminada, o saber cuales fueron mis respuestas que se eliminaron cuando se elimino ese usuario

Comment: @Japv no se elimina tu respuesta ni se elimina la pregunta cuando un usuario es eliminado(salvo casos excepcionales)

Comment: No es para nada subjetivo y si es malo, imaginate que el usuario que pierde los ptos tenga solamente 70ptos, si le quitan 50 entonces se quedaria con 20, para este usuario no es malo, es pesimo, ya que entre otras cosas perdio por ejemplo el privilegio de comentar en publicaciones que requiere como minimo 50 ptos

Comment: @Japv Pero ¿cuanto cuesta ganar 50 pts? ¿cuantas preguntas tiene que responder? Si responde bien a 2 preguntas entonces gana al menos 30 pts y si las dan 3UV ya los recupero. Es muy márginal, otra cosas sería que pierda 500pts

Comment: Por cierto las reglas cambian con los tiempos, las reglas no son eternas

Comment: A ti a lo mejor no te cuesta nada ganar 50 ptos pero hay otros a los que si les cuesta, aqui nada es marginal, lo bien ganado es bien ganado y nadie deberia quitartelo

Comment: @Japv Es justamente ese es tu posición pero no para toda la comunidad ya que justamente se sopeso en una balanza: minimizar el efecto de las cuentas títeres o quitar algunos puntos(por eso hay un tope), y se eligio lo primero, y eso es justo aunque no sea igualitario. Si tu aportación es buena entonces no solo obtendras  el voto del AP sino de otros miembros de la comunidad, asi que mi recomendación es: "haz tu aportación tan buena como puedas para que no solo el OP te de sus votos"

Comment: Dejemos esta regla para las cuentas titeres, pero que pasa cuando es el mismo usuario quien decide que le borren su cuenta o cuando es el mismo quien cierra su publicacion, que pasa entonces en esos casos, ademas ya te lo dije una vez en esta comunidad la cultura del voto es muy pobre

Comment: @Japv Estas uniendo colocando en un mismo caso: 1) Si el usuario quiere eliminar su propia cuenta, 2) El usuario quiere eliminar su publicación. En (1) es discutible pero lo de (2) es voluntad del mismo usuario y esta bien restringido: Si en una publicación alguna respuesta recibe un UV entonces el AP no podrá eliminar esa publicación.

Comment: Ok, y que hacemos con la opcion 1?

Comment: @Japv Ya estas delimitando tu requerimiento. Sobre (1) entonces hay 2 opciones: Se mantienen los puntos que dío el usuario o se eliminan, ambas opciones tienen buena  justificación para que sean la opción elegidas: Como señalas tu eliminar los puntos puede afectar a un usuario o como indico yo: Si una cuenta fue eliminada es como que si nunca existio por lo que los puntos que dío(a favo o en contra) tampoco deben existir. Y solo se eligio la segunda opción porque esos eventos son raros, personalmente he pédido en mi cuenta de SO 500 pts en estos años que para mi es márginal.

Comment: @Japv [cont.] Si eres un usuario nuevo entonces los puntos potenciales que te serán removidos seran muchos menos.

Comment: Y entonces, todo quedara igual? No cambiara nada?

Comment: @Japv Pues desde mi punto de vista que se aplique una opción u otra me es indiferente.

Comment: dio, sin tilde, no dío (diríamos /díiii-o/, que suena muy raro)